# Apache - disable file preprocessing

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

Apache tries parse my ***.tpl** files (which contain js/html – underscore templates). This is somethings I don't need at all.
So if I rename file to *.html, content is returned as is, and if that very file has "tpl" extension, I receive incorrectly processed result.

I worked the issue around by add line

```
AddType text/plain .tpl
```

to the config file **/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf**.

But question remains the same - why orifinally file was processed? Also if I explicitly specify

```
AddType application/octet-stream .tpl
```

file is processing also. I don't know how turn this behaviour off. Nothing suspicios in error.log / access.log (about parsing errors).

It is debian 7, Apache/2.2.22 (Debian). No **.htaccess**. Virtual host settings:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    AllowOverride all
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```